# Updating Color in Colors.xml, With Selected Color In Color-Picker

Tags: android, color-picker

I would like to ask about updating a color value in colors.xml, by Color-Picker .

Let's go into the story :

Preference Screen, with Color-Picker, And it's code as the following :

```
        <net.margaritov.preference.colorpicker.ColorPickerPreference
        android:key="pref_color"
        android:title="@string/pref_color_title"
        android:defaultValue="@color/picker_example"
        alphaSlider="true"
        hexValue="true" />
```

And for example, I've set the text color to "@color/picker_example", which is Red ( ugly, but it's an example ) .

What i want to do is, the user will open the color picker, and select the new color, when he hits the submit, the new color will replace the @picker_example => update the text color.

So, how to do this ?

Comment: You can't actually alter the XML value. The user's choice should be saved in `SharedPreferences`, and you should look up this value using the string `pref_color`.

Comment: In the preference activity
if (key.equals(color_pref_key)) {
                intent.putExtra(color_pref_key, prefs.getInt(key,
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.system_primary_color)));
            }
in the color forwarding 
Color.parseColor(Settings.color_pref_key
is that correct ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref